# Search the second max value by multiple conditions in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm new at power BI and i've a model with table that call DIVUCHIM_MONE.
I want to get the last  [Id] value for the [work_order].
The same [work_order] can be appear several time, the [Id] not.
For exmple:

```
Id  work_order
1   215353
2   215325
3   215325
4   215353
5   215221
6   215231
7   215221
8   215325
9   215353
10  215231
```

I expected to get:

```
Id  work_order  Id_Before
1   215353      0
2   215325      0
3   215325      2
4   215353      1
5   215221      0
6   215231      0
7   215221      5
8   215325      3
9   215353      4
10  215231      6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following measure

```
  _id = 
VAR _currentlyVisibleID =
    MAX ( 'Fact'[Id] )
VAR _immediatelyPrecedingByWO =
    CALCULATE (
        CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Fact'[Id] ), 'Fact'[Id] < _currentlyVisibleID ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Fact', 'Fact'[work_order] )
    )
RETURN
    _immediatelyPrecedingByWO+0
```

[image: Solution]

**`Edit`**

`Calculated Column`

```
Column = 
VAR _currentlyVisibleID =
    CALCULATE(MAX ( 'Fact'[Id] ))
VAR _immediatelyPrecedingByWO =
    CALCULATE (
        CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Fact'[Id] ), 'Fact'[Id] < _currentlyVisibleID ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Fact', 'Fact'[work_order] )
    )
RETURN
    _immediatelyPrecedingByWO+0
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for the solution, I do it with a new column and not a measure and I get in my first row the is OK but the other rows shows the bigger ID and not the last. I also do it as a measure and I saw that it's work, but I need a column and not a measure.

Comment: Great!!! It's work!
Thanks!!!